# Backbone sub views/plugins that are aware of when the parent view is loaded

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm developing a dynamic form for editing content where I need to be able to add backbone subviews/modules/plugins and bind them to markup rendered from another view. The special thing about this main form/view is that as a third party developer I'm not able to alter this view, so what I need is a loading mechanism for creating instances of sub views in backbone but only when the main view is loaded. I have made a small fiddle that shows what I want to do and in this example the view that contains the checkbox needs to be aware of when the editor view is loaded so I can create an instance of it and bind it to the correct el.

Here is the script I'm using

```
// This code cannot be altered by the developer who's creating the module/plugin
var EditorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#tpl-main-view').html()),

    initialize: function () {
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        var html = this.template();
        $(this.el).html(html);
        return this;
    }

});

// This module/plugin needs to be aware of when the editor view is loaded
var SubModule = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click input[type=checkbox]' : 'publish'
    },
    publish: function() {
        alert('publish...');
    }
});

var Container = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click button' : 'loadView'
    },
    loadView: function() {
        var view = new EditorView();
        $('body').append(view.render().el);
    }
});

var main = new Container({el: $('#container')});

var module = new SubModule({el: $('#sub-view')});
```

this is the html I'm using in my fiddle

```
<div id="container">
    <button>Load</button>
</div>
<script id="tpl-main-view" type="text/template">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit</legend>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <br />

            <!-- Sub module start -->
            <div id="sub-view">
                <label>Published</label>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <!-- Sub module end -->

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</script>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UtMeM/2/)

Updated my question with a possible answer but I don't know if this is the best way of solving it. Is it possible to solve this using require js or similar? I think Dojo have some way of determine when other views are loaded.

A possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/9phHk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You mention that EditorView cannot be altered but your fiddle contains modified code for EditorView which listens to a change event, if you are allowed to add events to the EditorView then your approach should work. If you want a way to not modify EditorView but listen to a keyup event then I think you can try the following:

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    // option 1: check the current active element id with the id of the input field
    // you are concerned about

    // option 2: check the model hasChanged value and display your sub view as needed
});
```